# Layout not showing for seperate route file

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have an express application using handlebars. I have one route file (index.js --> localhost:3000/) being used to serve some views. But then I also created another route file (agency.js --> localhost:3000/agency/) so that there's not hundreds of lines of code in one file.

The problem is that, when i load the /agency endpoint, it only shows the handlebars file. It does not use the default layout that is set in app.js.

When i load localhost:3000/ it displays the layout without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should really show what code you have, because your setup will be different than mine, so if I give you my code, it's complicated because I'm not using the defaults.

You have 2 problems.

1. You want to use different route files
2. You having problems with the layout files

Solution for 1: use app.use

index.js file

```
app.use('/agency', require(`agency`)) // make route use the route file in root/agency.js
```

agency.js file

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { // this is using your /agency and its only / because its using /agency. If you want /agency/test then you use /test
    res.render(`viewHandlebarsFile`) // calling your handlebar view file
})
```

handlebars main layout file (your default): Make sure you put this in the body tag, it will call your handlebar view file

{{{body}}}

How it works: your index.js file points the /agency route to your route file agency.js

Your agency.js get the handlebar view file.

Your handlebar view file is just the body only. Your defualt layout file will use the {{{body}}} tag and this body will call your handlebars view file.

Like I said, without knowing how you setup your defaults, its hard to help you without your codes. I've given you the key code to use that should work with what your setup is. Good luck to you.

Below I've got a skeleton layout for you if you're having problems.

app.js file located in your root folder

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'})) // change extension to .hbs
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', {
        content: 'This is some content', // for dynamic content, in view use {{content}} to call this data
        published: false
    })
})

app.use('/agency', require(`./agency`)) 

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server started on port' + app.get('port'))
})
```

agency.js file located in root folder

```
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const app = module.exports = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => { // this is using your /agency and its only / because its using /agency. If you want /agency/test then you use /test
    res.render(`view2`) // calling your handlebar view file
})
```

In your views folder located in root directory

home.hbs

```
<h1>Welcome Home Page</h1>
```

view2.hbs located in your views folder

```
<h1>View 2 page</h1>
```

Inside layouts folder thats inside your views folder

main.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Handlebars Express</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```